# Understanding the while loop with value false

Tags: javascript

Im relatively new to Javascript and as such trying to understand what it is I am writing.

I get the while loop eg:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
 console.log('i is less than 10');
 i++;
}
```

but what i dont understand is when do you use

```
while(false) {
document.write('do this');
}
document.write('do that');
```

the "false" value confuses me because i don't understand what i am checking against

Comment: "when do you use ..." - you don't.

Comment: *"i don't understand what i am checking against"* The loop body is executed as long as the condition evaluates to `false`. The `false` literal (obviously?) evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will never run. False is never true, so anything in `while(false) {...}` will not be executed.

You would not use this in practice. It effectively disables a block of code.

You asked what it is "checking against." It's checking to see if `false` evaluates to `true`. It doesn't, so it doesn't run anything in the `while` block.

Comment: so would you ever type while(false) ?

Comment: No. It's useless, unless you're trying to disable something temporarily for testing. But there's no reason not to just comment out the code in question, instead -- comments are easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

`while(false)` is a useless code because it won't output any or do any at all. The `while()` loop will always check for boolean conditions and that means that the statement inside it must return true or false. `True` and `False` are valid arguments inside the while loop. `while(false)` will not output any and `while(true)` will run infinitely.

Arguments inside the `while()` loop will always evaluate to `true` or `false`. Therefore if you have `var num = 5;` and `while(num==5)` then `(num==5)` will be evaluated to `true` and if the condition is not met then it will be `false` instead.

Comment: yes i get this part but what i don't understand is what is it checking against  to determine if it is true or false?

Comment: @Gavib: The `false` literal (obviously?) evaluates to the value false (not true). Think about like this: `while(x)` is the same as `while(Boolean(x) === true)`. So `while(false)` is the same `while(Boolean(false) === true)` which is false, because `false === true` is false.

Comment: @GavinWood false is the final value. You didn't check it against any.

Say you have `var num=5;` 
therefore:
`while(num==5)` is also `while(true)` and it will always equate to that.

Comment: ok so case and point i will never write while(false) or while(true)? even if a variable is set to a certain value?

Comment: No good programmer will ever write `while(false)` and `while(true)`. Always set a condition that can be met either true or false and make sure that it will not loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to test. You didn't really include that in your second code example. As long as you have a variable (or you want to see if it exists), you can do this, though.

If you want to loop while a variable is undefined, you can do it like this:

```
while(i == undefined) {
runCode()
}
```

if you want to run while a condition is false, (for instance, i = 10), you'd have to make it loop while a condition is true that would make the condition you're testing for false, like this:

```
while(i != 10) {
runCode()
}
```